# How to match two submitted values with google sheet cells and return html templates based on that

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15aBW7eoddWj_AiA032pMuUk7_GvI-xG6siVF5wJuh8g/edit#gid=2104954217

In Sheet1: I have some names in column C and their codes in column B

And Sheet2 where users submit their names and codes

I need to compare the new submitted name in Sheet2 with the names in Sheet1 and whenever we have a match, compare the newly submitted code with the relative code in Sheet1 at which;

- If the new submitted name matches with any name in Sheet1, proceed to match the code at which;

  - If the code matches with the code next to the name in Sheet1, return HTML template that says confirmed
  - If the code does not match with the code next to the name in Sheet1, return HTML template that says wrong code
- If the name does not match with any name in Sheet1, return HTML template that says the wrong name

I have tried the below code.gs:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Form.html")
    .evaluate()
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === "Timestamp" ? new Date() : e.parameter[header];
    });
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);

    var name = newRow[3];
    var code = newRow[2];

    var sh = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var names = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      if (names[i] == name) {
        var row = i;
        var existingCode = sh.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
        if (existingCode == code) {
          return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Confirmation.html")
            .evaluate()
            .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
        } else {
          return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("codeError.html")
            .evaluate()
            .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
        }
      } else {
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("nameError.html")
          .evaluate()
          .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({ result: "error", error: e })
    ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

But it gives wrong names all the time. The sheet is editable so feel free to use it and thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `row[3]` does not exist - the values in column D are populated by an Array formula in your sheet - not by your posted values. Also, if you want to compare the lower case versions of the names, you need to use column C in Sheet1 instead of column A
2. If you use a for loop the way you do - for each loop iteration where the name does not correpond with the row entry you will run into the name error situation and the `else` statement will directly call 'nameError.html'.

I recommend you to use instead [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) that not only retrieves either the name is preent in the sheet, but also returns you the position - so no need for loops.

**Sample:**

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10 * 1000);  
  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])    
    var name = sheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).getValue();
    var code = newRow[2];    
    var sh = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var names = sh.getRange(2, 3, sh.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
    if (names.flat().indexOf(name) != -1) {     
      var existingCode = sh.getRange(names.flat().indexOf(name)+2, 2).getValue();
      if (existingCode == code){
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Confirmation.html').evaluate()
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
      } else {
        return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('codeError.html').evaluate()
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
      }              
    }      
    else {
      return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('nameError.html').evaluate()
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    } 
  }  
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }  
  finally { lock.releaseLock() }
}
```

Comment: Yes, using indexOf() is a brilliant idea in this situation and it works much better than for looping. Thank you so much @ziganotschka